# Multidimensional integer

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA code, when defining the variables, what does it enable the code to do to define an integer variable with multiple ranges of values?

For example:

```
Dim iCount(a to b, x to y) as Integer
```

Comment: use this one: `Dim iCount() as Integer` and then (after initializing a,b,x,y) `Redim iCount(a To b, x To y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of Arrays in `VBA`. Fixed arrays where the limits are constants defined as

```
Dim A(1 to 100) as Long
```

and dynamic arrays defined as

```
N = 100
Dim A() as Long
ReDim(1 to N)
...
Erase A
```

Similarly for multi dimensional arrays

```
Dim A() as Long
ReDim(1 to N, 1 to M)
...
Erase A
```

Now for an example taking an array B of unknown size, and creating an array A by adding 1 to each value.

```
' Given a 1D array B() make a copy into A()
Dim A() as Long
Dim i_low as Long, i_high as Long, i as Long
' Discover array bounds of B
i_low = LBOUND(B,1) : i_high = UBOUND(B,1)
' Declare array size
ReDim A(i_low to i_high)
For i=i_low to i_high
  ' Calculate each element of the new array
  A(i) = B(i) + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Hi ja72, thanks for your response as I am sure I behind the curve on this but trying to learn more.  Taking a look at just the fixed array variety, I am sure there are multiple uses for a variable defined as an array, but is a primary purpose of this capability in VBA to allow for the same variable to be used with multiple values?  I can see a potential benefit of this is to limit the number of variables needed in code.

Comment: Adding on to the last comment as well, when there is a variable set as an array, if I needed the code to use each potential value in the array, say in a loop, do I have to create a line of code for each value in the array when it is used in code or is there a way to automatically loop through the values in the array?

Comment: To loop through the values of the array you need code like `For i=1 to N` where `N` is either known, or calculated using the `UBound()` function.

Comment: See edits above where one array is defined by a calculation from another array of unknown size.